# What's the easiest way of making a histogram in KDB?

Tags: kdb

If I've got a list of values `x`, what's the easiest way to make a histogram with bin-size `b`?

It seems like I could hack a complicated solution, but I feel like there must be a built-in function for this somewhere that I don't know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't heard about built-in histogram so far. But I would approach this task like below.

For fixed bucket size:

```
a: 0.39 0.51 0.51 0.4 0.17 0.3 0.78 0.53 0.71 0.41;
b: 0.1;
{count each group x xbar y}[b;a]
// returns 0.3 0.5 0.4 0.1 0.7!2 3 2 1 2j
```

For "floating" buckets:

```
a: 0.39 0.51 0.51 0.4 0.17 0.3 0.78 0.53 0.71 0.41;
b: -1 0.5 0.7 1;
{count each group x@x bin y}[b;a]
// returns -1 0.5 0.7!5 3 2j
```

Above functions return dictionary with bucket starts as keys and number of bucket occurrences as values.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of x values (let's assume x = 1000):

```
v:1000?1.0;
```

You can achieve what you need as follows:

```
b:0.1;
hist:(count') group xbar[b;v];
```

There are two points:

1. the keys in `hist` are **not sorted**
2. For the bucket, do you prefer to output the **left** or the **right** delimiter?

To solve for 1), you simply do:

```
hist:(asc key hist)#hist;
```

To solve for 2) - I mean, if you want to have the right delimiter:

```
hist:(+[b;key hist])!value hist;
```